# Swing AWTEventListener listening to 3rd party application

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im trying to create tool, which will close popup window in 3rd party application (written in java).

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(...);
```

But with this approach I can only listen to events from windows created in my own application. Is there any way to receive events from other apps? Maybe I should start them from my app?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen directly to UI elements in other processes... which honestly you should be happy about because it could would open up many software vulnerabilities.

There are two ways I've used to achieve cross application communication. Both require specific (as opposed to built-in) design to work.

1. Starting the 2nd application in Java via ProcessBuilder (or the old implementations for doing such in System). You can read and write to process in/out/error streams. Of course, the process has got to be set up to also communicate its streams
2. Listen on a ServerSocket in one of the applications and connect from the other. When you do this, you need to devise a common port as well as a common communication protocol.

I hope this helps